# How to load CDC into Redshift database?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Can anyone tell me CDC /incremental load methods in Redshift using SQL?

I know one method upsert but other than this there are another methods to do like insert followed by delete etc..

Comment: Yes... insert + delete + update is the same as merge. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes...i want to know all methods to load incremental data into redshift with sql and i want to know how to avoid duplicates?

Comment: This site isn't about people doing your research for you. This site is about you trying something and returning with a specific question.

Comment: Ok thank you ...i will check ...

Answer (score 2):

Redshift doesn't support `UPSERT` or `MERGE` in SQL but we have a few data merge examples in the docs: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-examples.html

Remember that you can use these patterns inside a transaction so you can rollback if something fails.